# Meaning of "emphasized upon" in the given context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Please help me figure out the meaning of the words "emphasized upon" in the following context:

"The ‘Grishastashram’ **emphasized upon** the Bhakti movement, and did not
permit saints to take to sanyas without the consent of wife."

Here the word "sanyas" means "renunciation".

For more context, please visit the following link:

https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Pcf1nrvUwD0C&pg=PA110&lpg=PA110&dq=%22The+%E2%80%98Grishastashram%E2%80%99+emphasized+upon+the+Bhakti+movement,+and+did+not+permit+saints+to+take+to+sanyas+without+the+consent+of+wife.+%22&source=bl&ots=IPeL2szjvS&sig=lLogide-NvNk5DM47W4jkEk-M78&hl=hi&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjttMeK8sTWAhUHKo8KHRSnCtoQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22The%20%E2%80%98Grishastashram%E2%80%99%20emphasized%20upon%20the%20Bhakti%20movement%2C%20and%20did%20not%20permit%20saints%20to%20take%20to%20sanyas%20without%20the%20consent%20of%20wife.%20%22&f=false

Answer (score 1):

that's a very poor phrasing - I'd understand it, but it isnt *right*. 
I don't fully understand the context material but here is a syntactically acceptable alternative with optional extra words depending on its actual deeper meaning.

"The ‘Grishastashram’ **placed (his/an) emphasis** upon *or* **favoured/prioritised** (supporting?) the Bhakti movement"

also "to take to sanyas without the consent of wife." should probably be "to take to sanyas with the consent of **their wives**" if I understand the intended meaning correctly. Saints is plural, so "wives" must also be plural.